# Alternating between iterators in Python

Tags: python, iterator

What is the most efficient way to alternate taking values from different iterators in Python, so that, for example, `alternate(xrange(1, 7, 2), xrange(2, 8, 2))` would yield 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. I know one way to implement it would be:

```
def alternate(*iters):
    while True:
        for i in iters:
            try:
                yield i.next()
            except StopIteration:
                pass
```

But is there a more efficient or cleaner way? (Or, better yet, an `itertools` function I missed?)

Comment: Do you mean 1, 2, 7, 8, 2, 2?

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243865/how-do-i-merge-two-python-iterators

Comment: @Sean Devlin:  No, 1 2 3 4 5 6 is correct.  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what about zip? you may also try izip from itertools

```
>>> zip(xrange(1, 7, 2),xrange(2, 8 , 2))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

if this is not what you want, please give more examples in your question post.

Comment: On its own, izip isn't enough for my purposes. But putting a chain around izip, like `chain.from_iterable(izip(iterables))` does work. I guess that's the cool thing about iterables. Thanks!

Comment: The trouble with `zip` in this instance is that it will evaluate the iterators immediately, forcing you to forego generator semantics.

Comment: Which would be especially problematic considering that my original use case for this was iterators that generated an infinite number of values.

Answer (score 18):

For a "clean" implementation, you want

```
itertools.chain(*itertools.izip(*iters))
```

but maybe you want

```
itertools.chain(*itertools.izip_longest(*iters))
```

Comment: Does this exhaust the generator before passing it on to izip and then chain?

Comment: @Dan If `iters` was a generator, it would exhaust it, at least in python 2; running `def z(*iters): print(type(iters)); print(iters)` then `z(*(i for i in xrange(1,18)))` prints `<type 'tuple'>` and `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)`.

Answer (score 7):

See `roundrobin` [in the `itertools` "Recipes" section](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#recipes).  It's a more general version of alternate.

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define `alternate` like this:

```
import itertools
def alternate(*iters):   
    for elt in itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        itertools.izip(*iters)):
        yield elt

print list(alternate(xrange(1, 7, 2), xrange(2, 8, 2)))
```

This leaves open the question of what to do if one iterator stops before another.
If you'd like to continue until the longest iterator is exhausted, then you could use `itertools.izip_longest` in place of `itertools.izip`.

```
import itertools
def alternate(*iters):   
    for elt in itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        itertools.izip_longest(*iters)):
        yield elt
print list(alternate(xrange(1, 7, 2), xrange(2, 10, 2)))
```

This will put yield

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, None, 8]
```

Note `None` is yielded when the iterator xrange(1,7,2) raises StopIteration (has no more elements).

If you'd like to just skip the iterator instead of yielding `None`, you could do this:

```
Dummy=object()

def alternate(*iters):   
    for elt in itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        itertools.izip_longest(*iters,fillvalue=Dummy)):
        if elt is not Dummy:
            yield elt
```

Comment: Might be cleaner to define Dummy as `Dummy = object()`

Answer (score 2):

If they're the same length, itertools.izip can be leveraged like so:

```
def alternate(*iters):
    for row in itertools.izip(*iters):
       for i in row:
           yield i
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your attempt:

1. You don't wrap each object in `iters` with `iter()` so it will fail with iterables such as `list`; and
2. By `pass`ing on `StopIteration` your generator is an infinite loop.

Some simple code that does solves both those issues and is still easy to read and understand:

```
def alternate(*iters):
    iters = [iter(i) for i in iters]
    while True:
        for i in iters:
            yield next(i)

>>> list(alternate(range(1, 7, 2), range(2, 8, 2)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```