# merging two dictionaries of lists with the same keys in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**My problem:**

I'm trying to merge two dictionaries of lists into a new dictionary, alternating the elements of the 2 original lists for each key to create the new list for that key.

So for example, if I have two dictionaries:

```
strings = {'S1' : ["string0", "string1", "string2"], 'S2' : ["string0", "string1"]}

Ns = {'S1' : ["N0", "N1"], 'S2' : ["N0"]}
```

I want to merge these two dictionaries so that the final dictionary will look like:

```
strings_and_Ns = {'S1': ["string0", "N0", "string1", "N1", "string2"], 'S2': ["string0", "N0", "string1"]}
```

or better yet, have the strings from the list joined together for every key, like:

```
strings_and_Ns = {'S1': ["string0N0string1N1string2"], 'S2': ["string0N0string1"]}
```

(I'm trying to connect together DNA sequence fragments.)

**What I've tried so far:**

**zip**

```
 for S in Ns:   
     newsequence = [zip(strings[S], Ns[S])]
     newsequence_joined = ''.join(str(newsequence))
     strings_and_Ns[species] = newsequence_joined
```

This does not join the sequences together into a single string, and the order of the strings are still incorrect.

**Using a defaultdict**

```
from collections import defaultdict
strings_and_Ns = defaultdict(list)

    for S in (strings, Ns):
        for key, value in S.iteritems():
        strings_and_Ns[key].append(value)
```

The order of the strings for this is also incorrect...

**Somehow moving along the lists for each key...**

```
for S in strings: 
    list = strings[S]
    L = len(list)
    for i in range(L):
        strings_and_Ns[S] = strings_and_Ns[S] + strings[S][i] + strings[S][i]
```

Comment: How exactly to you want to interweave the lists if they have different lengths?  There is more than one way I can think of.

Comment: The new list should always start with strings and end with strings. The len(Ns) is always len(strings)-1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strings_and_Ns = {}
for k,v in strings.items():
    pairs = zip(v, Ns[k] + ['']) # add empty to avoid need for zip_longest()
    flat = (item for sub in pairs for item in sub)
    strings_and_Ns[k] = ''.join(flat)
```

`flat` is built according to the accepted answer here: [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) or with list slicing stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion). The result looks pretty smart with itertools.

```
strings_and_Ns = {}
for skey, sval in strings.iteritems():
    iters = [iter(sval), iter(Ns[skey])]
    strings_and_Ns[skey] = ["".join(it.next() for it in itertools.cycle(iters))]
```

You have to take care about the corresponding length of your lists. If one iterator raise `StopIteration` the merging ends for that key.

Comment: This use of `cycle()` is clever.  Perhaps a little too clever.  :)

Answer (score 2):

To alternate `x`, `y` iterables inserting `default` for missing values:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def alternate(x, y, default):
    return (item for pair in izip_longest(x, y, default) for item in pair)
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/LdawFA)

```
a = {'S1' : ["string0", "string1", "string2"], 'S2' : ["string0", "string1"]}
b = {'S1' : ["N0", "N1"], 'S2' : ["N0"]}
assert a.keys() == b.keys()
merged = {k: ''.join(alternate(a[k], b[k], '')) for k in a}
print(merged)
```

#### Output

```
{'S2': 'string0N0string1', 'S1': 'string0N0string1N1string2'}
```

Answer (score 1):

[itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)  will take care of the uneven length lists, then just use `str.join` to join into one single string.

```
strings = {'S1' : ["string0", "string1", "string2"], 'S2' : ["string0", "string1"]}

Ns = {'S1' : ["N0", "N1"], 'S2' : ["N0"]}

from itertools import izip_longest as iz

strings_and_Ns = {k:["".join([a+b for a, b in iz(strings[k],v,fillvalue="")])] for k,v in Ns.items()}

print(strings_and_Ns)
{'S2': ['string0N0string1'], 'S1': ['string0N0string1N1string2']}
```

Which is the same as:

```
strings_and_Ns  = {}
for k, v in Ns.items():
     strings_and_Ns[k] = ["".join([a + b for a, b in iz(strings[k], v, fillvalue="")])]
```

Using `izip_longest` means the code will work no matter which dict's values contain more elements.

Comment: Ok, you are editing all the time. I was confused. I think this version is faster but less readable.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other solutions posted, but I would move some of it off into a function

```
import itertools   

def alternate(*iters, **kwargs):
    return itertools.chain(*itertools.izip_longest(*iters, **kwargs))

result = {k: ''.join(alternate(strings[k], Ns[k] + [''])) for k in Ns}
print result
```

Gives:

```
{'S2': 'string0N0string1', 'S1': 'string0N0string1N1string2'}
```

The `alternate` function is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2017923/66349. It takes iterables as arguments and chains together items from each one successively (using `izip_longest` as 
Padraic Cunningham did).

You can either specify `fillvalue=''` to handle the different length lists, or just manually pad out the shorter list as I have done above (which assumes `Ns` will always be one shorter than `strings`).

If you have an older python version that doesn't support dict comprehension, you could use this instead

```
result = dict((k, ''.join(alternate(strings[k], Ns[k] + ['']))) for k in Ns)
```

Comment: you could use `chain.from_iterable()`.