# Python - iterating beginning with the middle of the list and then checking either side

Tags: python, iteration

Really not sure where this fits. Say, I have a list:

```
>>>a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

How can I iterate it in such a way, that it will check 4 first, then 5, then 3, then 6, and then 2(and so on for bigger lists)? I have only been able to work out the middle which is

```
>>>middle = [len(a)/2 if len(a) % 2 = 0 else ((len(a)+1)/2)]
```

I'm really not sure how to apply this, nor am I sure that my way of working out the middle is the best way. I've thought of grabbing two indexes and after each iteration, adding 1 and subtracting 1 from each respective index but have no idea how to make a for loop abide by these rules.

With regards as to why I need this; it's for analysing a valid play in a card game and will check from the middle card of a given hand up to each end until a valid card can be played.

Comment: Why start in the middle? A valid card is just a s likely to be at the beginning or end as the middle. Why not start at the ends and work your way in?

Comment: Just for the sake of a smarter AI considering everything else.

Comment: what do you mean by "check 4 first, then 5, then 3, then 6, and then 2(and so on for bigger lists"?

Comment: I don't see how that makes for smarter AI. You're are still doing the same thing, picking the first valid card. Where you start in a list of cards (that I assume is randomly drawn) doesn't make that choice any different.

Comment: Ian it's because the better choice is closer to the middle for this case. Wajdi that means check the value in the middle, and then check the values +- 1 from the middle, then +- 2 from the middle, etc.

Comment: How are you determining the order of the cards in the first place? It sounds like you should just sort them first based on their value

Comment: The cards have actually already been presorted. I dunno... This is some hybrid game and yeah, it's weird.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just keep removing from the middle of list:

```
lst = range(1, 8)
while lst:
    print lst.pop(len(lst)/2)
```

This is not the best solution performance-wise (removing item from list is expensive), but it is simple - good enough for a simple game.

EDIT:

More performance stable solution would be a generator, that calculates element position:

```
def iter_from_middle(lst):
    try:
        middle = len(lst)/2
        yield lst[middle]

        for shift in range(1, middle+1):
            # order is important!
            yield lst[middle - shift]
            yield lst[middle + shift]

    except IndexError: # occures on lst[len(lst)] or for empty list
        raise StopIteration
```

Comment: Hey, this seems like the simplest solution. Could I duplicate the list and then iterate through the duplicated list so as to preserve the values in the original list? I'm thinking shallow copies could come into play here too.

Comment: I have another idea, inspired by @Ami Tavory, I add it in few minutes ;-)

Comment: If the length of the list is not an even value, how does this work?

Comment: it quits either when `not  middle - shift >= 0` or when `middle + shift > len(lst)` - when the later occurs, `IndexError` is raised, which is conversed to `StopIteration` inside our except, marking end of generator.

Comment: you can print `shift` and `middle` inside the loop and in `except` clause, to see the flow, then test it on few lists ;-)

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding how it would always iterate through `3` first in `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. What would I have to change for it to iterate through the `2` first?

Comment: in the first line add `lst = lst[::-1]` ;o) - which reverses list; but more seriously, it becomes complicated then, because lst[-1] does not raise exception. So you should add condition to break out of the loop on this. Probably would be better to write a `while` loop instead, but if you want to inquire, post a seperate question, please.

Comment: I applied this into my function, with the `lst = lst[::-1]` and it did raise the `IndexError` and complete the loop. Cheers.

Comment: `middle` should be an int, should use `len(lst) // 2` instead of `len(lst) / 2` (`TypeError: range indices must be integers or slices, not float`)

Answer (score 6):

To begin with, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243865/how-do-i-merge-two-python-iterators) is a very useful general purpose utility to interleave two sequences:

```
def imerge(a, b):
    for i, j in itertools.izip_longest(a,b):
        yield i
        if j is not None:
            yield j
```

with that, you just need to `imerge`

```
a[len(a) / 2: ]
```

with

```
reversed(a[: len(a) / 2])
```

Comment: @m.wasowski Thanks! That was a good point. Have updated. In the new version, fiddling with the fill-value of ``izip_longest`` would also take care of lists containing ``None``; that's the basic idea of this answer, though.

Comment: Seems all the experts think your answer is the best. I'm not sure if I should mark yours right or not, because your solution is actually too advanced for me, whilst wasowski's I understand perfectly.

Comment: You should mark whatever works for **you**, so feel free to accept his. I think the other answers are really great, BTW, and have learned from them (mine is more intuitive to me, but that's subjective).

Answer (score 6):

You could also play index games, for example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> [a[(len(a) + (~i, i)[i%2]) // 2] for i in range(len(a))]
[4, 5, 3, 6, 2, 7, 1]

>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> [a[(len(a) + (~i, i)[i%2]) // 2] for i in range(len(a))]
[4, 5, 3, 6, 2, 7, 1, 8]
```

Comment: pretty nice. this is a much smarter version of what i'm doing in my answer (yours was posted first).

Comment: I love this bit negation trick, but I would personally crucify anyone who dared to put something like this into our codebase :D

Comment: @m.wasowski I don't think it's that bad, at least not because of the bit negation. After all, it's a straight-forward way to index from the back. Quite neat for example to get the median of a sorted list: `m = len(a)//2; median = (a[m] + a[~m]) / 2`.

Comment: I don't mind bit negation, just took me a minute or two to figure out how does it ALL works - today, knowing the context. Probably I would be perplexed if I run on something like this two weeks from now. And I think when you read a complex code all day long, the last thing you need is more complexity in simple stuff - I prefer to read through code quickly without adding too much to my mind stack ;)

Comment: @m.wasowski Yeah, ok, the whole took me a minute or four to *write* as well :-). Mostly a fun solution just because I can.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generator that yields alternating indexes for any given provided length. It could probably be improved/shorter, but it works.

```
def backNforth(length):
    if length == 0:
        return
    else:
        middle = length//2
        yield middle

        for ind in range(1, middle + 1):
            if length > (2 * ind - 1):
                yield middle - ind
            if length > (2 * ind):
                yield middle + ind 

# for testing:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = range(9)
    for _ in backNforth(len(r)):
        print(r[_])
```

Using that, you can just do this to produce a list of items in the order you want:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
a_prime = [a[_] for _ in backNforth(len(a))]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the middle elements, **I needed their index as well**. I found Wasowski's answer very helpful, and modified it:

```
def iter_from_middle(lst):
    index = len(lst)//2
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        index = index+i*(-1)**i
        yield index, lst[index]

>>> my_list = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> [(index, item) for index, item in iter_from_middle(my_list)]
[(3, 13), (2, 12), (4, 14), (1, 11), (5, 15), (0, 10)]
```